# Connecting To Mongoose And Using It With Functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have been trying to find ways to connect to mongoose once when my app starts, then use that connection from then to query the database on without having to reconnect all over again and trigger the error i've been getting, but I don't know what to do. Here is the error I get when I refresh the page (localhost:8080):

```
'connection error: { [Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.] state: 1 }'

var http = require("http");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongodata = [];

function RequestHandler(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received.");

    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
    db.once("open", function(callback) {
            console.log("Connected.");

    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var motorSchema = new Schema ({
            RPM: String,
            Horsepower: String
    });

    var Motor = mongoose.model("Motor", motorSchema);

            Motor.find(function(err, motors) {
                    console.log(motors[2].Horsepower);
                    var i;

                    for (i=0; i < motors.length; i++) {
                            mongodata[i] = motors[i];
            }
    });
});

            response.write("Test.");
            response.end();
}

http.createServer(RequestHandler).listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require("http");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongodata = [];
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function(callback) {
    console.log("Connected.");
});
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var motorSchema = new Schema({
    RPM: String,
    Horsepower: String
});

var Motor = mongoose.model("Motor", motorSchema);

function RequestHandler(request, response) {
    console.log("Request received.");


    Motor.find(function(err, motors) {
        console.log(motors[2].Horsepower);
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < motors.length; i++) {
            mongodata[i] = motors[i];
        }
    });


    response.write("Test.");
    response.end();
}
http.createServer(RequestHandler).listen(8080);
```

Comment: @NicholasBrown Can you please marked answered and upvote?